# ctypes is hidden (unsatisfied 'exist_if') error when using dune on wsl

Tags: ocaml, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ocaml-dune

I am using wsl ubuntu on my windows 10 machine and am trying to build an ocaml project(https://github.com/adamrk/llvm-ocaml-tutorial) using dune. Unfortunately, i am getting this error:

```
# dune build bin/kaleidoscope.exe
File "/home/impor/.opam/4.10.0/lib/ctypes/META", line 1, characters 0-0:
Error: Library "ctypes.foreign.threaded" in
/home/impor/.opam/4.10.0/lib/ctypes is hidden (unsatisfied 'exist_if').
-> required by library "ctypes.foreign" in
   /home/impor/.opam/4.10.0/lib/ctypes
-> required by executable kaleidoscope in bin/dune:2
Hint: try: dune external-lib-deps --missing bin/kaleidoscope.exe
```

I couldn't find any documentation about this so I am very lost.

```
# dune external-lib-deps --missing bin/kaleidoscope.exe
```

does nothing

Comment: What did you do to install dependencies? What is the output of `opam list`? Did you install opam package `conf-pkg-config`? Is `ctypes-foreign` installed?

Comment: ctypes-foreign was not installed. Installing it fixed this. Thank you.

Comment: I'll add it as an answer for others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to not having opam package `ctypes-foreign` installed.